# In iOS How to capture frames from a video file as stream of UIImages?

Tags: ios, ios4, avfoundation

I am interested in reading Video file as a series of UIImages on iOS. Is there anyway to do that using AVFoundation APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Create an AVAssetReader with the video track of the file. With an AVAssetReaderTrackOutput, you can send it the copyNextSampleBuffer message to receive a CMSampleBuffer. Each call will produce another frame from the video.

Inside the [AVFoundation Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html) there is sample code showing how to set up an AVAssetReader as well as a method for making the conversion from CMSampleBuffer to UIImage.